# Most Recent Entry

Tags: sql

I have joined two tables

```
select * from prod 
inner join stock_inventory_new on prod.prod_cd=stock_inventory_new.prod_cd
```

And I want to bring back only the latest entries for prod_cd, do I need to insert a MAX date?

Comment: Edit your question and (1) tag with the database you are using. (2) provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This should be order by date as descending order and limit no of rows.

Mysql:-

```
select * from prod 
inner join stock_inventory_new on prod.prod_cd=stock_inventory_new.prod_cd 
order by [date] desc Limit 20
```

MS sql:-

```
select TOP 20 from prod inner join stock_inventory_new on 
prod.prod_cd=stock_inventory_new.prod_cd order by [date] desc
```